# Why does this line throw an exception?

Tags: c#, xna, nullreferenceexception

I have been troubled by this for a while now, this is the code I have:

```
TILArray = new string[Width, Height];
int t = 0;
TILArray[t, t] = "";
TILArray[t, t] = "";
for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
    {
        if (TILList[x][y] != null)
        {
            TILArray[0, 0] = TILList[x][y];
            Tiles[x, y] = Content.Load<Tile>(TILList[x][y]);
        }// This line throws the excetion
    }
}
```

The line that throws the exception is actually the right curly brace marked above.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TileEngine.dll
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Is this in release mode or debug mode?

Comment: The exception won't *actually* be on the brace. Is `TILList` itself non-null?

Comment: it all works if it's outside the loop

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352817/transferring-a-list-of-a-list-to-a-2d-array?

Comment: Is your 'Tiles' array initialized ?

Comment: yes it is, in the constructor of the class

Comment: You're mixing jagged arrays with multidimensional arrays. This code wont compile. Which do you use? (Jagged arrays might explain your problem)

Comment: If you look at a combination of the Call Stack, in Visual Studio; the Stack Trace in the exception; and the actual live values of your current objects (whilst stepping through the code), then I'm sure you will find the error. A `NullReferenceException` is going to be fairly easy to spot, since a variable is going to contain a null reference.

Comment: I use both so that I can serialize it with the content pipeline to xml

Comment: Ok I fixed it by reinitializing the Tile[,] array when I set the width and height with the correct lengths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to reinitialize the Tiles array when I set the width and height
That fixed it

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it's `Content` that is null and you're calling the method before the game's `LoadContent` method is called, or before you set up `Content`.

Ensure you're setting the `Content` member correctly. This should be done for you in the default game template. Also, ensure you're loading content after (or within) the game's `LoadContent` method.

Comment: +1. The total ignorance of the poster regarding standard naming conventions sadly makes it hard to ind out whether "Content" is a variable or a class.

Comment: @annonymously: There is a content member (of `Game`). I never mentioned a content class. (The class is `ContentManager`).

Comment: @annonymously: I got the wrong end of the stick as your question was a bit unclear. You can just accept your own answer (once the wait period expires).